# Cardinality of sets and bijections

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble understanding the following propositions:

**Let A and B be sets. Then A and B have the same cardinality if and only if there is a bijection from A to B.**

*and*

**Let $f : X \to X$ be a function. f is a bijection if and only if there exists a function $g : X \to X$ such that $f(g(x)) = g(f(x)) = x$ for all $x$.**

Does the first result only hold for finite sets? Consider the function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(n) = 2n$. This is *not* onto and therefore *not* a bijection, but I understand that the set of even natural numbers and the set of natural numbers have the same size (the even natural numbers are countably infinite). Does this contradict the first proposition?

On the other hand, is there any function $g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(g(n)) = g(f(n)) = n$ for all $n$? Letting $g(n) = \frac{n}{2}$ does not suffice, since this is not defined for odd $n$ (the image of odd $n$ under $g$ is *not* a natural number and so is not in the codomain).

Answer (score 1):

*"Does the first result only hold for finite sets?"*

No.  This definitions is specifically for infinite sets. It works for finite sets, but finite set cardinality is trivially easy.

*"Consider the function f:N→N defined by f(n)=2n". This is not onto and therefore not a bijection,"*

Right.  Lots of functions aren't bijections.  But as $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb N$ are the same thing it *has* to have the same cardinality to itself!

If you want a bijection $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb N$ then simply use the identity function, $f(x) = x$.  It is a bijection.  But you don't need bijections to show a set has the same cardinality as itself!

*" but I understand that the set of even natural numbers and the set of natural numbers have the same size (the even natural numbers are countably infinite). Does this contradict the first proposition?"*

Absolutely not.  $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow 2\mathbb N=\{\text{all even numbers}\}$ defined $f(n)=2n$ **is** onto and injective so it *is* a bijection to $2\mathbb N$.

So $\mathbb N$ and $2\mathbb N$ have the same cardinality.

You seem to be confused because $f(n) =2n$ is not surjective to *the natural numbers*.  But it *is* surjective to the even numbers.

*"On the other hand, is there any function g:N→N
such that f(g(n))=g(f(n))=n for all n?"*

Infinitely.  $f(n) = g(n) = n$.   $f(2n-1) = 2n;f(2n)=2n-1$ (if odd make it even by adding one; if its even make it odd by subtracting one) $g(2n+1) = 2n$ and $g(2n) = 2n+1$ (the exact opposite). $f(n) = n$ unless $n =5$ or $n=27$; $f(5) =27; f(27)= 5$; $g(n) = f(n)$; Etc.

*" Letting g(n)=n/2 does not suffice, since this is not defined for odd n (the image of odd n under g is not a natural number and so is not in the codomain)."*

But $f(n) = 2n$ is bijection *to the even numbers*.  So $g(n) = \frac n2 $ *does* suffice.

$f: \mathbb N \rightarrow 2\mathbb N$; $f(n) =2n$ is a bijection and

$g: 2\mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb N$; $f(n) = \frac n/2$ is its inverse.

You seem to be insisting on mapping $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ when you should be mapping it to the even numbers.

Answer (score 0):

> Consider the function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(n) = 2n$. This is *not* onto and therefore *not* a bijection,

Correct $f: n\mapsto 2n$ is not a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$.

There are, however, functions that are bijective from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$.   The identity function is the most obvious.   $\operatorname {id}: n\mapsto n$.

> but I understand that the set of even natural numbers and the set of natural numbers have the same size (the even natural numbers are countably infinite). Does this contradict the first proposition?

No, because $f$ *is* a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $2\Bbb N$.

---

Note, the second proposition only concerns functions whose image is the codomain.